# Fail to run OpenVINO demo

Tags: openvino

I am trying to install OpenVINO in a custom location (Windows 10). So far installation occurs without error. However, when I try to run any of the samples, I get this output:

```
.\demo_benchmark_app.bat
target_precision = FP16
Python 3.7.0
[setupvars.bat] OpenVINO environment initialized
INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR is set to C:\<user_dir>\openvino\install
Python 3.7.0
ECHO is off.
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\<user_dir>\\openvino\\install\\deployment_tools\\demo\\..\\open_model_zoo\\tools\\downloader\\requirements.in'
Error
```

I do not have a folder `..\\open_model_zoo`. Was this supposed to be created during installation? Can I download and/or create the folder post installation?

Below are my installation commands:

```
cd <user_dir>
mkdir openvino  
cd openvino/  
git clone https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino.git .  
git submodule update --init --recursive  
mkdir build  
mkdir install  
cd build  
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DNGRAPH_ONNX_IMPORT_ENABLE=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\<user_dir>\openvino\install" ..
cmake --build . --config Release  
cmake --install . --config Release
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Model Zoo is a separate folder. It is not created during 'build from source' installation. You can clone the Open Model Zoo repo from this GitHub link: https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo.git.

Then, place the cloned repo in the *deployment_tools* directory.

Comment: This definitly helps a lot. However, I now get this error when running the demo scripts: `'install_prerequisites_caffe.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`. This bat file is located in the model-optimizer\install_prerequisites folder. However, running this before the demo does not remove the error. Should this folder be moved and/or copied somewhere into the install directory?

Comment: Seems like the 'install_prerequisites_caffe.bat' is missing from your 'install' directory. I would suggest you rebuild and reinstall the OpenVINO toolkit.